# Where should I dispatch actions to call services to retrieve data needed before initial app load?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I need to call some services to retrieve data before showing any UI.  Some of the data returned will be used for conditional rendering of error scenarios etc. on app load. Would it be best to do this just before ReactDOM.render()?

Comment: Best to do that inside of `componentDidMount`

Comment: I need to call these services before mounting any components or rendering to the DOM, so componentDidMount will not work.

Comment: then do it in top component and render other child when data ready - strange requirement - why not render conditionally `<Loading/>` ?

Comment: Written an answer with short comments on how you can go about what you want to do.

Comment: I think conditional rendering will work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
class Custom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: null, loading: false };
  }

  getData = () => {
    // This is just to simulate a delayed API fetch/response.
    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({loading: false, data: {a: 'data loaded'}), 1000);
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData(); // Call your data fetching method here...
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, data } = this.state;

    // you can also return a loading spinner instead of null;
    // returning null ensures nothing is rendered in the DOM.    
    if (loading) return null;

    // At this point, data is already available...
    return (
      <div>
        // rest of your markup.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Custom />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call them in `componentDidMount` 
You can display a loader until the content is finished loading.